# why this trigger always loop?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

i try to use trigger , when i insert in table penduduk, then in table muda will insert too, actually this trigger is work, but this trigger become loop, when i insert (123) in penduduk, then insert again (1234) then the result will be (123,1234,123,1234) , am i right to use 'From penduduk' ? or i should use 'FROM inserted' ? cause when i use FROM inserted there is no result
my query like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_muda
ON penduduk
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO muda (noktp,tgl_lahir)
SELECT noktp, tgl_lahir FROM penduduk
WHERE umur < 27
```

Comment: You should and a condition so only records that haven't been inserted before are added.

Comment: it mean where like this ? Where muda.primary = penduduk.primary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently grabbing all matching rows from `penduduk` rather than the `inserted` logical table.  You might change your trigger to the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_muda
ON penduduk
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO muda (noktp,tgl_lahir)
SELECT noktp, tgl_lahir FROM inserted -- Use inserted, not the base table
WHERE umur < 27
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx):

> DML triggers use the deleted and inserted logical (conceptual) tables. They are structurally similar to the table on which the trigger is defined, that is, the table on which the user action is tried. The deleted and inserted tables hold the old values or new values of the rows that may be changed by the user action.

Comment: when i use inserted that come with no result

Comment: Does it have a result without `WHERE umur < 27`? Please share your insert statement and values if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Select noktb, tgl_lahir from inserted
```

If you're interested in inserting based on the newly inserted data. Your select seems to be capable of returning many items as it stands, which explains the "looping"/duplication.